# How to avoid blank lines corresponding to empty <tr> tags

Tags: asp.net, html

I am displaying several asp.net panel controls using an html table. Initially the panels are set as visible = false. Depending upon the data from database, some of the panels will be made visible. The problem is if the second and tenth panels are made visible, there are several blank lines are displayed in the page since there are several empty  tags created corresponding to invisble panels. please let me know how avoid the blank lines.

Thanks

Comment: With out code, and such a small detail.... please share your code.

Comment: How can something that is invisible cause blnk lines? Obviously it's not all invisible. You should use CSS for [**margin**](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp) instead of using tables for your layout.

Comment: Can't you just put the <tr></tr> tags inside the panels?

Comment: Ant P's suggestion resolved the issue. I put the <tr> tags inside the panels.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

give style instead of visible property

```
<div style="display:none"></div>
```

then from code behind make `display : "block"` this will hide your element completely and there will be no empty spaces.

Comment: `Visible` in codebehind means that it doesn't exist at all on clientside. The problem is not `display` or `Visible` but a table for the layout. He should simply use CSS for the margin instead of empty rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you place your `<tr>` tags within the `Panel` control, these will not be rendered out when `Panel.Visible == false`:

```
<asp:Panel ...>
    <tr>...</tr>
</asp:Panel>
```